# How run shell command in C

Tags: c, shell, curl, awk

In my code I need to know about the location of some IP addresses. For getting this information, I send queries to a website with free API. Because C does not have this ability to send queries, I decide to run a shell script in my code. The returned response from the website is as follows:

```
"IP address","US","United States","MI","Michigan","Dearborn","48121","42.3223","-83.1763","505","313"
```

I need just these two number: `"42.3223","-83.1763"` (latitude and longitude)
My shell command is:

```
curl freegeoip.net/csv/{IPaddress} | awk -F'","' '{print $8,$9}'
```

For running the shell code into C , I used system() function, but this function does not return the values of `$8` and `$9`

```
int main ()
{
int i, ret = system("curl freegeoip.net/csv/{IPaddress} | awk -F'","' '{print $8,$9}'");
        printf("My val= %d\n",i);
        return 0;
}
```

I need these two values to be returned into my C code.
I do not want to use popen(), because it opens and closes a file each time, and the number of my queries is too high which it would be too costly.

Comment: *"I do not want to use popen(), because it opens and closes a file each time"* ... it's not clear what you mean here. `popen()` is exactly what you need to be using.

Comment: Not to use `popen()`? So what else you want? you already know solution.

Comment: if you not want to use `popen()` then use `system("command> command.out")` to redirect the output.

Comment: "C does not have the ability to send queries"... see [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).  Also `popen` opens and closes a pipe which may be somewhat costly but nothing compared to spawning a shell and the network overhead.  If you really want to reduce overhead incorporate the query into your program rather than using external programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because C does not have this ability to send queries

Sure it does.  What do you think `curl` and your shell are written in?  Of course, it's not *easy* to make HTTP requests in C, but it's certainly *possible*.

> I do not want to use popen(), because it opens and closes a file each time, and the number of my queries is too high which it would be too costly.

Your premise is wrong and your conclusion is wrong.  `popen()` doesn't open a file, it opens a pipe, which has a file descriptor associated with it, and is returned to your code via `FILE*` object.  When you have a pipe, the data that gets written to the pipe by one process never goes to disk, it's just stored in memory by the OS.  So the child process writes data to the in-memory pipe, and the parent process reads that data back, all without hitting disk.

Even ignoring that, the performance bottleneck of this program is not going to be pipeline.  The network is an order of magnitude slower than disk access (or anything else run locally), so the bottleneck is going to be the data transfer.  After that, the next bottleneck will be process creation, which is not cheap, but it's still way cheaper than network operations.  You're worrying about the wrong things here, performance-wise.

Just use `popen()` here, it's exactly what you need.  If you need to run a large number of queries, consider running them all in one command line to curl so that it can enable [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining).  Without that, each request would have to be sent on a separate TCP stream, which would increase overall latency.  If you really need very high performance, don't shell out to a subprocess—I'd suggest integrating [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) directly into your program.